Algebraic extension of F containing all zeros of F[x] is algebraically closed
This is Exercise 32.34 in Fraleigh's book, 'A first course in abstract algebra'.

Show that if $E$ is an algebraic extension of a field $F$ and contains
all zeros in ${\bar{F}}$ of every $f(x)\in F[x]$ , then $E$ is an algebraically closed
field.

I refer to this: proof verification: algebraic extension (of F) containing all zeros of F[x] is algebraically closed.
I completely agree with the solution in the above link. However, I am curious if my solution is also valid:
${F \le \bar{F} \le E.\ \bar{F}}$ is algebraically closed field. ${\bar{F}}$ has no proper extension. ${\bar{F} = E}$  . Therefore, ${E}$ is algebraically closed field.

What are $E$ and $\overline{F}$?

I just wrote the problem in the text. I think ${\bar{F}}$ is the algebraic closure of F over F in E.

Your argument assumes that the algebraic closure (i) is somehow unique; and (ii) must be contained in $E$; neither is valid. It is also false that $\overline{F}$ has no proper extensions: it has no proper algebraic extensions.

Your statement "$\overline{F}$ has no proper extension" is wrong. In fact, you may find that you haven't used the condition of  "$E / F$ is an algebraic extension."
There is no nontrivial algebraic extension over algebraic closed fields. However, there may be transcendental ones.
For example, the field of complex numbers, $\mathbb{C}$, is algebraically closed. But the field of rational functions with complex coefficients, $\mathbb{C}(t)$, satisfies $\mathbb{C} \subseteq \mathbb{C}(t)$ and $\mathbb{C} \neq \mathbb{C}(t)$.
